# consumir datos de un archivo JSON en angular2+

Tags: json, angular

Necesito obtener datos de un archivo externo, por ejemplo
dejar 2 rutas de servicios en un archivo externo dentro de la carpeta `assets`, luego desde el `servicio.ts` obtener esas URL del archivo externo.
es posible obtener datos de un archivo externo en angular 2+?

en lo posible no usar `httpClient`.

Gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin usar `httpClient` la alternativa es importar el json, transcribo del link original pues es bastante explicativo:

En ES6/ES2015, podes importar un archivo json directamente al código. Por ejemplo,

`example.json`

```
{
    "name": "testing"
}
```

Lo podes importar en ES6/ES2015 de esta manera:

```
// ES6/ES2015
// app.js
import * as data from './example.json';
const word = data.name;
console.log(word); // output 'testing'
```

Sin embargo, en Typescript, este código dará error:

> Cannot find module 'example.json'

Solución: Usar "Wildcard Module Name", agregar en el archivo de definiciones:

`typings.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Luego el import funciona así

```
// Typescript
// app.ts
import * as data from './example.json';
const word = (<any>data).name;
console.log(word); // output 'testing'
```

referencias:

https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

https://github.com/chybie/ts-json

Comment: Me ha servido amigo mio, me salvaste la vida

Answer (score 0):

con httpClient (testeado y funcionando):

```
getJson(){
 // puedes colocar esta funcion en tu servicio e injectando el servicio acceder
// a el desde cualquier componente
  let path = './assets/i18n/en.json';
  return this.http.get(path);
}
getMyFile(){
 //luego simplemente te suscribes a tu funcion cuando quieras obtener el json
// this.servicio.getJson().subscribe(data => {console.log(data)}) si la funcion
// se encuentra en el servicio
 getJson.subscribe(data => { console.log(data, 'tu json')} )
}
```

sin httpClient (deberia funcionar, no testeado):

```
getJson(): Observable {
return this.http.get('./assets/i18n/en.json'))
    .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
    }
)
.catch(this.handleError);
}
```

por ultimo recomendaria ir pasandote a httpClient, es superior en todos los aspectos, reduce la cantidad de lineas de codigo, es mas legible, tiene mas opciones, mejor documentacion, y no es dificil pasarse de uno al otro.