# ¿Como obtener una variable en archivo externo js y usarla en angular cli?

Tags: javascript, angular

Buenas tengo la duda como puedo usar por ejemplo una variable declarada en js en un archivo externo y usarla en angular cli ejemplo:

```
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0

archivo.js

function myFunction(){
  var variable
}
```

comunicar con `componente.component.ts`

estaba viendo muchas respuestas por ejemplo en el archivo componente importar algo asi

```
 import * as xJS from '../../../assets/js/archivo.js';
```

para usarlo pero no funciona el archivo componente se encuentra en otra carpeta externa.

¿quisiera saber si hay forma? de solamente llamarla o llamar a la funcion por ejemplo `import variable from "archivo.js"` o `function`

Comment: Por entender un poco mejor tu pregunta, tienes un fichero que es externo al código de Angular, y lo que quieres es utilizar "archivo.js" e importar algo de su contenido, ¿correcto? ¿Dónde está ese fichero que mencionas?

Comment: si son valores estáticos podes importarlos desde un json ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/163752/81450 si son funciones ahí cambia el asunto

Comment: El archivo js debe estar en la carpeta assets por eso lo pongo alli la ruta import * as xJS from '../../../assets/js/archivo.js'; y el archivo componente se ubicaria por ejemplo ../components/componente/componente.components.ts

Comment: Es conveniente usarlo en Json? para su llamado de preferencia o que es conveniente? yo sugiero es mas factible como llamarlo desde la carpeta que esta ubicado aunque es mi opinion claro estoy a sugerencias jeje por ejemplo import '../../../assets/js/archivo.js';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El archivo exterior tiene que EXPORTAR la variable o la funcion que quieres IMPORTAR.

En archivo.js

```
export var variable = 'variable que se exporta'

export function myFunction() {
   var variable
   return variable // O lo que quieras hacer con tu funcion :D
}
```

En tu `componente.component.ts` puedes importarlo:

```
import * as xJS from '../../../assets/js/archivo.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './componente.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./componente.component.scss']
})
export class ComponenteComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log(xJS.variable);
    console.log(xJS.myFunction());
  }
```

O puedes hacer

```
import { variable, myFunction } from '../../../assets/js/archivo.js';
@Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './componente.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./componente.component.scss']
    })
    export class ComponenteComponent {
      constructor() {
        console.log(variable);
        console.log(myFunction());
    }
```

Comment: Me late tu idea lo intentare!

Comment: En la archivo de ts.config.json tambien debo insertar el campo "allowJs":true y algo mas?

Comment: Es que me marca el siguiente error antes de insertar el campo allowJs 
 Module '../../../assets/js/archivo.js' was resolved to '/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/myapp/myapp/src/assets/js/archivo.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
PD:pongo dos veces myapp porque estoy probando en otra carpeta

Comment: Despues de poner el campo allowJs me dice: File 'src/assets/js/archivo.js' is not a module. alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Cual opción es la que estas usando...?

Comment: Use las dos y no hallo un arreglo para las dos jeje

Comment: Parece ser problema de typescript. Puedes darme tu tsconfig.json ??

Comment: ts.config.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}

Le agregué la linea allowJs para quitar el error de que necesita el comando allowJs:true

Comment: No habia tomado en cuenta tus configuraciones, las que estas dando en tu pregunta, te recomiendo que actualices todos los paquetes pues ya estamos en la version 6 de angular y en 2.7 de TypeScript

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias

Comment: Si ha sido de ayuda puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta ;)