# Creando un servicio en Angular:¿Como hacer un método que devuelva el contenido de un json que tengo en assets?

Tags: angular

Seguro que la respuesta es mas fácil que la pregunta :D,

Estoy empezando con angular, y quiero crear un servicio que me devuelva los datos  que tengo en un json en mi equipo.

Mi código es :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';//comprobar si hace falta
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';//comprobar si hace falta

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestPersonasService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
    getPersonas(): Observable<any[]> {
    //return this.http.get<any[]>('/home/rick/cursoAngulardia2/src/assets/personas.json');
    //return this.http.get<any[]>('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');
    }
}
```

si le pongo la dirección del json (que tengo en asset) no funciona.
si pongo una dirección que devuelve un json si.

¿Que es lo que he entendido mal?
Gracias.

La consola me da el siguiente error:

> error: "↵↵↵↵Error↵↵↵
>
> ```
> Cannot GET
> /personas.json
> ```
>
> ↵↵↵" headers: HttpHeaders
>   {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ} message:
>   "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/personas.json: 404
>   Not Found" name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 404 statusText:
>   "Not Found" url: "http://localhost:4200/personas.json"

SOLUCION:

Todo funciona bien si pongo esto como respuesta del getPersonas:

`return this.http.get<any[]>('assets/personas.json');`

No obstante, voy a calificar la respuesta de RRGT19 como buena por que ha sido muy constructiva.
De hecho e conseguido que fucione a su manera, aunque no he conseguido eliminar el error:

`Consider using ‘–resolveJsonModule’ to import module with ‘.json’ extension`

---

Si alguien ademas me dice porque no funciona con la ruta absoluta lo agradecería.

Comment: relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/163487/81450

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependiendo de tu versión de Angular y de TypeScript, la solución sería diferente. Angular 7 está basado en TypeScript 3, ya que desde TypeScript 2.9 soporta importación directa de JSON's, la solución es fácil.

**Método 1:**

Primero, necesitas preparar la aplicación con algunos flags adicionales en el `tsconfig.json`. Debes agregar las siguientes dos opciones:

1. ResolveJSONModule. `--resolveJsonModule` permite la importación, extrayendo los tipos de los archivos JSON.
2. ESModuleInterop. `--esModuleInterop` permite importaciones predeterminadas desde módulos sin exportación predeterminada. Esto es necesario ya que un archivo .json no tiene salida predeterminada.

Ejemplo de como quedaría el `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
 "compileOnSave": false,
  "lib": [
   "es2018",
   "dom"
  ],
  ......
  ....
  ..
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true
 }
}
```

Si `tsconf.json` está configurado, básicamente ya has terminado y puedes importar un archivo .json con una simple declaración de importación y sin http.get.

Dentro de un componente, debe importar el archivo .json:

```
import miJSON from '../assets/example.json';
```

Puedes usarlo como si fuera un objeto (de hecho, es uno):

```
constructor() {
  console.log(miJSON.nombre)
}
```

**Método 2:**

Dentro de un componente, importar el .json y asignarlo a una variable:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import sampleData from './data.json';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
Users: any = sampleData;
}
```

Ahora, verás un error en consola que dice:

> Consider using ‘–resolveJsonModule’ to import module with ‘.json’
>   extension

Para solucionar este problema, crearemos un archivo con el nombre de `json-typings.d.ts` en la carpeta raíz de la aplicación y pegaremos el siguiente código:

```
declare module "*.json" {
const value: any;
export default value;
}
```

Con este código, se está indicando que todos los módulos que tienen un especificador que termina en .json tienen una única exportación llamada default que es de tipo any.

Ahora su aplicación Angular 7 está lista para servir los datos del archivo JSON local.

Para verlo en pantalla, vaya a `app.component.html` y pegue el siguiente código en él:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let users of Users">
<h2>{{users.name}}</h2>
</li>
</ul>
```

Sería todo. Estas son formas fáciles y rápidas, seguro habrán otras ideas por ahí.

Comment: Es importante que sea dentro de un serivio.

Answer (score 0):

En mi experiencia me gustaría centralizarlo en un servicio.

1. crearía en los `environment` una variable con la ruta del localhost (desarrollo) y otra con la del hosting de la aplicación (desarrollo)

```
     export const environment = {
          production: false,
            baseHref: "/",
        }
    
    export const environment = {
          production: true,
            baseHref: "http://miweb.com",
        }
```

2. Crearía un servicio donde accederia a los datos de manera centralizada

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Predefinidos } from '../interfaces/predefinidos.interfaces';
    import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment'
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class PredefinidosService {
      private jsonUrl: string = environment.baseHref
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    
      getPredefinidos(): Observable<Predefinidos> {
        return this.http.get<Predefinidos>(`${this.jsonUrl}assets/json/predefinidos.json`);
      }
    }
```

3. luego accedería al servicio desde cualquier componente

```
constructor(private predfinidosService: PredefinidosService){}
```